# Passing a list of values to Oracle using Python

Tags: python, oracle

I'm trying to define a list of values (id numbers) and pass them to SQL that's querying Oracle tables.

This code works as long as I only include one id.

```
named_params = {'ids':'123456548'}
query = """
select PEBEMPL_ECLS_CODE 
from PEBEMPL
inner join SPRIDEN on spriden_pidm = pebempl_pidm 
where SPRIDEN_CHANGE_IND is null
and SPRIDEN_ID in :ids
"""
df = pd.read_sql(query, connection, params=named_params)
```

What's the correct syntax for doing the same but passing a list of ids?

This code, for example, doesn't work:

```
idlist = ['123456548','546465464']
named_params = {'ids':idlist}
query = """
select PEBEMPL_ECLS_CODE 
from PEBEMPL
inner join SPRIDEN on spriden_pidm = pebempl_pidm 
where SPRIDEN_CHANGE_IND is null
and SPRIDEN_ID in :ids
"""
df = pd.read_sql(query, connection, params=named_params)
```

Error Returned:

```
': ORA-01484: arrays can only be bound to PL/SQL statements
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You will need to create a separate bind parameter for each item in the list, and then pass the list of ids into `read_sql()`:

```
idlist = ['123456548','546465464']

in_vars = ','.join(':%d' % i for i in range(len(idlist)))

query = """
select PEBEMPL_ECLS_CODE 
from PEBEMPL
inner join SPRIDEN on spriden_pidm = pebempl_pidm 
where SPRIDEN_CHANGE_IND is null
and SPRIDEN_ID in (%s)
""" % in_vars
df = pd.read_sql(query, connection, params=idlist)
```

To avoid any confusion, the above example talks to Oracle using Pandas `read_sql()` function. For people working with a `cursor` object directly, then the syntax is:

```
cursor.execute(query, params)
```

Comment: I get the following error with this code: "ORA-01008: not all variables bound".  Any suggestion?

Comment: Sorry my mistake - the `idlist` should be passed as a keyword argument - as `params=idlist`. I have updated the answer.

Comment: just for completeness' sake: link to the relevant [cx_oracle documenation](https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/bind.html#binding-multiple-values-to-a-sql-where-in-clause)

Answer (score 0):

I believe you will have to pass the parameters as string. May be join all the ID's you want to query with a comma and send it as a string to SPRIDEN_ID.